# How to trigger refetch when the requirement need to go other path?

Tags: typescript, react-query

So far I can pass refetch function on a child component. The problem is when I have to go to other page and use redux. (Open dialog for new path link). And in that page I will trigger this refetch function. While redux for sure can not save a function refetch. What is the proper way to solve this ?

```
 const { data: getWorkerGroupsResponse, refetch } = useQuery(
  'get-worker-group',
   async () => getWorkerGroups(projectId as string),
   {
      enabled: !!projectId,
   },
  );
```

In code above I have to pass refetch to other page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React query handles refetches automatically when the query key changes. You should not find the need to call `refetch` just because an ID has changed.

You have a bug in your component that the query key does not include the id, so from RQ perspective, there is just one query. If you introduce it, it will be fine even without refetching manually:

```
const { data: getWorkerGroupsResponse, refetch } = useQuery(
  ['get-worker-group', projectId], // projectId should be part of queryKey
  async () => getWorkerGroups(projectId as string),
  {
    enabled: !!projectId,
  },
);
```

Now, when `projectId` changes, react query picks up on the fact that the `queryKey` you provided changes and will rerun the query using the new value.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. What if the trigger is a boolean ?. For example I want to update a worker detail on a Dialog (another path) using redux. In order to do that, I need to refetch all worker from parent component. Can I use boolean as a queryKey?. Is this proper way`enabled: !!projectId || onSuccessUpdateWorker` ?

Comment: If you want that, the most idiomatic way in React Query is to invalidate the original query using query client - `queryClient.invalidateQueries(['get-worker-group', projectId])` as a callback of what you are doing in the dialog. If you are using a mutation to update, you can have this in the `onSuccess` of the mutation.

Comment: A question, why do I need invalidate the queries ?. What I am doing above looks fine and no error.

Comment: You only need to invalidate, when you change the data so that youre not displaying the old data.